# When a user clicks, how can I collect the x/y as well as any link that may have been clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a feeling that a button - that is not a link - is misleading, but need evidence. So I want to record link clicks for analytic purposes, but also want non-link clicks to be recorded as x-y coordinates.

So first I wanted to use $('a'), but that would only collect link clicks, so I want to do something like this:

```
$('html').click(function(event){
  var x = event.clientX; //will these change if the user has scrolled?
  var y = event.clientY;
  var link_clicked = 0;

  //this is what I'm not sure about:
  if($(this) <contains a link that was clicked>){
    link_clicked = $('<link clicked>').attr('title');
  }
  //so how do I find what link was clicked?

  var data = {x:x;y:y;link_clicked:link_clicked};
  $post(ajax_url, data, function(response){
    //do nothing
  });
});
```

So my first question is: In the event of a link clicked, how do I find the link within the html element that was clicked?

My 2nd question is: Do clientX/Y change when the user scrolls? For instance I want x=420 to be the same if the user clicks on the same link in different scroll positions.

Comment: So you want to record every click on a page, determine from the x,y coordinates if it was a link, then post that data back to the server, each click? (just making sure I'm understanding)

Comment: have you tried .. event.target

Comment: @tymeJV I want to always record x/y coordinates. If a link was clicked I want to know which one.

Comment: But the x/y coordinates of the clicked element are likely to be different across different users' devices (mobile phones, tablets, laptops, desktops and the various monitor sizes); rather than recording *where* the user clicked, why not check *what* they clicked on (using `e.target`, for example)?

Comment: Your edits are really making a case for identifying the target, not the coordinates.

Comment: Check updated-answer below for your second question.

Comment: If you got your answer below, please mark it accepted. OR please do tell the issues you are facing. thanks. :)

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt testing the targeting. I think just getting the lowest-level element clicked will suffice, so I'm making sure that's what I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   var myItem=$('#myLink');
    $('html').click(function(event){
      var x = event.clientX; //will these change if the user has scrolled?
      var y = event.clientY;
      var link_clicked = 0;
      var clickedItem=event.target;
      if(clickedItem==myItem)
        console.log('clicked')
     ...
    });
```

EDIT:

```
var myItem=$('#myLink');
var x=myItem.offset().left;
var y=myItem.offset().top;
var clientX=event.clientX;
var clientY=event.clientY;
```

From that you can get the relative x/y values.. If I understand you correctly.

**Regarding your second question.**..
Yes clientX/clientY do change with the scrolling because they are browser specific(relative to top-browser-bar, you can think) rather than document-specific.

Comment: Ok, if I did this (also to address @David Thomas's point),  can I then record the x/y relative to the target? Will that improve accuracy and paint a clearer picture across devices or are we doomed to not be able to tell where the user clicked because of different window sizes/devices?

Comment: I'd like to add to this response that target gives you a lot of information back, and it's not easy to find a single element-defining attribute of target.